# How to replace specific entries of a Numpy array based on its content

Tags: python, numpy

So lets say I have a simple matrix made out of ndarrays (just an example of how  part of the data might look like):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([['1.0', 'Miami'],
   ['2.0', 'Boston'],
   ['1.4', 'Miami']])
```

I want to do data analisys in this complex data set ;) - I want to transform 'Miami' in 0 and Boston in 1 in order to use a really fancy ML algorithm. What is a good way to accomplish this in Python. (I am not asking for the obvious one of iterating and using a dictionary / if sentence to replace the entry) but more if there's a better way using Numpy or  native Python to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is a good tool for this.
First convert the array to a DataFrame:

```
In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['value', 'city'])
```

and then [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) entries from the city column:

```
In [13]: df.city = df.city.replace({'Miami': 0, 'Boston': 1})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  value city
0   1.0    0
1   2.0    1
2   1.4    0
```

Comment: I thought there was a way of doing it really clean without using a library. But this looks OK. I am going to start using Pandas.